# Weird css issue - Can not load a style depending on the browser

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have my `main.jsp` page wich contains this code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <script src="/targets/js/jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/targets/jsp/uploadify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/targets/css/cssPicker.css">

    <!-- ko template: { name: showView } --><!-- /ko -->
```

It is initializing some components as scripts and css. I'm calling `cssPicker.css` which contains the below code:

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/targets/jsp/targetsMSIE.css">
<!--[endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/targets/css/targets.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

But the style is not applying.

I have never played with css before and I'm pretty sure that the way I'm trying to call the sheet is incorrect. Please give me an advice on how to call correctly the sheet when someone is using IE and when someone is using another browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

All browsers except IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

All browsers.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/targets/css/targets.css">
```

[**Conditional Stylesheets**](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)  should help you to understand better.

I doubt you are not referring CSS locations properly `"/targets/jsp/targetsMSIE.css"` should this be `"/targets/css/targetsMSIE.css"`

Comment: Yes, but it is not applying for some reason. :(

Comment: Recheck your code, try clearing your browsers cache.
If you are deploying in `localhost:8080` check this location http://localhost:8080/targets/jsp/targetsMSIE.css can you see css in your browser?